# CSS - transferring stylesheets over to Wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, html

I've built the front-end HTML/CSS code for a site which now needs transferring onto Wordpress. I'm using the html5blank theme as this was recommended for such purposes. I've watched a tutorial by Chris Lam and it all seems quite straightforward.
However, I'm having quite a few issues with my stylesheets - some rules seem to be applying correctly and some don't which is very strange. As per the tutorial all I've done is delete the styling code in the style.css file and replace it with my own. 
Why would some rules apply and not others? Do I need to add something to another file (function.php?) that will allow my styling rules to work?

By way of an example, here's how my header and top section looks in my front-end home page -

[image: Front-end version]

And here's the (horrific looking) Wordpress version -

[image: Wordpress version]

I've re-set the background image to include the link for the Wordpress version -

```
section#home {

    height: 400px;

    background: url("http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/homepagemain.jpg") center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    overflow: hidden;

    position: relative;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to want to appear.

On the nav bar, I've had to replace the  tags with the following code as per the requirements in the header.php file -

```
<nav>
      <?php html5blank_nav(); ?>
</nav>
```

Just wrapping the php code within an  tag has no effect.

I've read that some themes require child/parent themes but that this shouldn't apply to the HTML5blank theme as its effectively an empty shell. 
The same code has been transferred across into the style.css file. Do I have to delete the normalise.css files also? I was using reset.css for the front-end version. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```css
/* GENERAL */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans:100,200,400,700,700i,800,800i');

body {
 font-family: "Merriweather Sans", sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 1.5;
 color: #333333;
}


body {
  
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  
}

.container {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}


header {
 background: #ffffff;
 height: 100px;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 10;
}


.left-header { background:white; width:50%; float:left; height: 100px; }


.right-header { background:white; width:50%; float:right; height: 50px;  }

.right-header-top { background: white; float: right; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin-right: 100px; }

.right-header-bottom  { background: white; float: left; width: 100%; height: 100%; }

#logo {

 margin-left: 60px;
 margin-top: 50px;
}

nav {
 float: left;
 font-weight: 400;
}

nav a {
 color: #000000;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-right:  25px;
 font-size: 12px;
 
}

div#contact {
 
 float: right;
 margin-right: 20px;
}

div#contact img {
 display: inline-block;
 
 border: 10px;
 margin: 20px;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;

}

div#contact p {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 25px;
 
 
 font-size: 10px;
}


.right-header-bottom i {
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 border: 15px;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

a {
 color: #000000;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
 color: #000000;
}

/* HOME PAGE */

section#home {

    height: 400px;
   
    background: url(../images/homepagemain.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    overflow: hidden;

    position: relative;
}

#agencyimage {

 position: absolute;
 margin: 0;
   top: 40%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}



.showreel {
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.showreel, .showreel > div.seemore {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex:1;
}
.showreel, .showreel > div.seeour {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex:1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.showreel p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.showreel i {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.seemore  {
  margin-left: 30px;
}


.seeour i {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Feature Media</title>
 <meta name="description" content="Video technology and production">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  
</head>

<body>
  
 <header>
        <div class="left-header">
            <img src="images/Logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo" style="width:250px;height:30px;">
        </div>
    <div class="right-header">
         <div class="right-header-top">
            <div id="contact">
                <img src="images/phone.png">
                <p>0113 220 5265</p>
                <img src="images/email.png">
                <p>hello@featuremedia.co.uk</p>
            </div>    
         </div>
         <div class="right-header-bottom">
            <nav>
                <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
                <a href="business.html">PRODUCTS</a>
                <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
                <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
                <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
            </nav>

                <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </div>
    </div>
 </header>

    <section id="home">

        <a href="agency.html"><img src="images/AGENCY-BUSINESS.png" id="agencyimage" style="width: 150px; height: 250px;"></a>

        <div class="container showreel">
            <div class="seemore">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color:#fff"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-stack-1x" style="color: #000000;"></i>
                </span>
                <p>SEE MORE</p>
            </div>
            <div class="seeour">
                <p>SEE OUR SHOWREEL</p>
                <i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: I'm afraid there are just too many variables here that will make getting an answer difficult...

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone Yeah, I can understand that. Is there a standard way, though, to upload css files onto Wordpress? Could there be something I'm missing that's glaringly obvious to a seasoned WP developer?

Comment: Not really a standard way. If your HTML and CSS are identical it doesn't matter if you use WordPress, flat files or any other framework...

Comment: When inspecting your page using chrome's developer tools - where does it say its looking for that background image?

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone I've included my skeleton css code at the foot of the style.css file - could this be messing with the styling?

Comment: @GordonSmith What do you mean?

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead If you inspect the page (by right clicking on the page and clicking 'inspect') - then mouse over the image area where the big banner image should show up - in the inspector code, you'll see in the css where it is calling for that background image. It will probably have an exclamation point to the left of it showing that the background image isn't loading. If you mouse over the URL for that background image, it will tell you where its trying to pull that background image from. If you can find out where, then you can adjust your code accordingly. Let me know what you find.

Comment: Are you working on this locally only? Or do you have a URL where I can take a look at the broken version of the site?

Comment: @GordonSmith Locally only. It's so strange, on the tutorial he just copies his stylesheet across and it works straight away. I can't find anything on google to suggest this is a problem so it must be something dead simple that I just can't see.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead when you copied your CSS over to the wordpress stylesheet, did you include your /images/ folder with all of its content inside the theme directory? I think you're having a paths issue. That's why I was trying to get you to check the path to the banner image, to find out where your browser is looking for the banner image. The code inspector in your browser should show that the image links in the CSS file are broken. Once you figure out where its looking for those images, you can adjust your paths accordingly.

Comment: Also, consider loading your CSS a different way when using wordpress: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/loading-css-into-wordpress-the-right-way--cms-20402

Comment: @GordonSmith I've downloaded all the images onto the Wordpress media file and changed the links. The others are working but the one I'm putting in the css file isn't which is strange.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead - Its okay, you can still make them work from your CSS file. I can see that your path in your CSS file is set to: 'background: url(../images/homepagemain.jpg)'. try changing the path to exclude '../' then make sure your images are in your theme folder so your path to your images are 'http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/theme-name/images/image-name.jpg' but the css file reference should be 'background: url(images/homepagemain.jpg)' if you include the images folder with the images in your theme.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead Checking in to see if you've worked this out.

Comment: @GordonSmith Hi, apologies, I was tied up with something and away from my computer. The code above is the exact link that I've got in my wordpress CSS style.css file - is this incorrect ?

Comment: @GordonSmith When I copied the code across I literally copied the code straight from the css file and pasted it into the corresponding WP file, I copied the images over separately.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead Which folder did you place the images folder in?

Comment: @GordonSmith In wp? In the Media library.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead Okay, and the styles.css is in the theme folder, correct? localhost/wp-content/themes/theme-name/style.css

Comment: @GordonSmith Yes, correct.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead I would recommend putting the images that you've uploaded through the media library, into a folder named 'images' in the theme folder instead of putting them in the media library. Then  css file image paths should be 'images/image-name.jpg' instead of '../images/image-name.jpg'. The images should show up at that point. The same applies for your css files you're trying to reference, put them in the theme folder in a folder called 'css' and they should connect also.

Answer (score 2):

it happens when your style-sheet is not properly added to your homepage.

You are giving this path, but this is not including the stylesheet, because the path is not correct.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
```

try to add this code before your **css** directory

```
<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>
```

So, it will be like that

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>/css/reset.css" />
```

It will gives the base url of the site, so this code becomes
www.xyz.com/css/"your css file"

Do this for all link attribute for css, and make sure that all css files put up in that css folder.

Comment: Do I put this in the header.php file? Or does this go somewhere else - at the tope of the style.css file? This seems to make sense - I thought it was a path issue - but just need to clarify where exactly this code goes. Also do I use bloginfo or pageinfo ?

Comment: Yes, you have to put this code in header.php, where you are including all the necessary stylesheets for the site. The function **bloginfo** returns the site information. Where  `stylesheet_directory` is a parameter of that function. you can find it more from here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo

Comment: Okay, thanks. So, regardless of whether you're building a website or a blog you would put bloginfo for that line of code?

Comment: Yes, If you are converting HTML template to Wordpress, you can use this code to include the css files.

Comment: Okay, I'm using the html5blank theme as it looks like this is the easiest to use when transferring front-end files over to wordpress.

Comment: Yes and you can make the images dynamic from this code also like:
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>/images/Logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo" style="width:250px;height:30px;">

It gives the theme's style sheet path, So it will include the css and images as well.

Comment: Hi, I've had to reboot my whole site because of a database issue so haven't been able to apply the stylesheet code you suggested until now. I'm affaraid your solution hasn't changed anything - have you any idea why this is the case?

Comment: No it will not change anything. You can use it without worries